# Firebase Realtime Database doesn't save data from sign up page

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on sign up page of application in Swift. The part of authentication in Firebase works well, but the database doesn't save any information I request. Can anyone help?

My code:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userEmail,password: userPassword, completion: {(User, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error as Any)
        return
    }
    guard let uid = User?.user.uid else {return}
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL:"Database-URL")
    let userReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)

    let values = ["Firstname": userFirstName,"email": userEmail]
    userReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
    })
})
```

The console prints an **error**

> Optional(Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission denied"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied})

Comment: Did you check the error that you are printing when error is not nil?

Comment: @SahilManchanda I only saw this error: Optional(Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied})

Comment: have a look at this question. it might help you go in right direction
https://stackoverflow.com/q/40291114/2299040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the database in a project in the new Firebase Console is only readable/writeable by authenticated users:

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null"
   }
 }
```

See the quickstart for the Firebase Database security rules.

Since you're not signing the user in from your code, the database denies you access to the data. To solve that you will either need to allow unauthenticated access to your database, or sign in the user before accessing the database.

Allow unauthenticated access to your database
The simplest workaround for the moment (until the tutorial gets updated) is to go into the Database panel in the console for you project, select the Rules tab and replace the contents with these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
}
```

This makes your new database readable and writeable by everyone. Be certain to secure your database again before you go into production, otherwise somebody is likely to start abusing it.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be sure but the completion for `createUser` doesnot give you User and error rather AuthResult and Error. So you have to get the user from result as below

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData, error) in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint("FIREBASE ERROR : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if let authData = authData {
                let user = authData.user //here get the user from result
                self.saveToDB(user: user) . //save the user to database
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the new code for firebase from may 2019. just change false to true like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```